# What is the rationale to use weights and biases in a neural network?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, fuzzy-logic

Searched a lot of research papers, blogs and videos but couldnt find an acceptable answer for choosing the weights and biases in neural network. Few people have mentioned to use weights randomly but if that is the case isnt that is uncertain (fuzzy)?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Are you asking how they are estimated, or why they exist at all? If it is the latter, it is because they are simple models of biological neurons. If you eliminate these parameters, only hyper parameters would remain; the topology, activation functions, and optimization algorithm. Randomization is an _initialization strategy_; the are no longer random once optimization is complete.

Comment: Emre, "simple models of biological neurons" that is a severe stretch. How about, weights associate an importance to an input and the bias allows for non-zero centered functions. The nodes in a NN are mathematical constructs. Very far from biological neurons. The closest is probably ReLU.

Comment: @JahKnows  Yes i totally agree "weights associate an importance to an input and the bias allows for non-zero centered functions". But the question is, which is have specifically mentioned in the details that how do you first initialize them? How do you choose their values? randomly? or what....

Comment: Yeah randomization does work. Just set them to be within an appropriate range of zero. I usually use a Gaussian distribution centered at 0 with a variance close to the variance of my input feature space. Then just go from there. But it also works if you set them all to zero.

Comment: @JahKnows: Thanx for the reply. So can I conclude that this random selection is dependent on the programmer of the NN. And that, various programmers may have different sets of values for weights? And irrespective of selection of weights NN will perform same or different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Weight Initialization**

Weights can be initialized by either setting them all to zero. Or by setting them randomly using a Gaussian distribution centered at 0 with a variance similar to the values of your input features.

**Is every initialization going to give you the same results?**

No. Neural networks (NNs) converge to a local minimum. Thus, different initialization of the weights will cause the loss function to be minimized to a different value. If you are unhappy with your results you can always do random restarts with different weight initialization.